# Build an SSRS Dataset that Queries for Data Dependent on Results From a Stored Procedure That Creates a Temp Table to Store Results?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, azure-sql-database, ssrs-2012

I need to build an SSRS report that displays query results from a SQL Azure table. However, one of my where conditions will check for data extracted from a stored procedure (exec team param1, param2) result set. Adding to the complication is that the stored procedure creates a temp table (`tempteam`) to store the results. How can I write a query for the data I need that specifies the `tempteam` contents in my where clause?

Sample code

```
exec team 9596, 2

select * from tempteam
```

Tempteam sample results

```
        consid
        9596
        23456
        24354
        20965
        ....
        ....
        ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just use the "TEMP" table in the **WHERE** clause of your query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM SOME_TABLE 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT consid FROM tempteam)
```

I don't think the "TEMP" table is actually a normal SQL Temporary table since it doesn't have a hashtag (`#tempteam`) in front of it - it looks like it's an actual table stored in a database.

Comment: You're right. It's not technically temp table. But the data in the table changes every time the proc is invoked. So I'd need to incorporate the proc in the SSRS datasets someway.

Comment: What I've done is built the query as you've said. Because this report is for my use, I'll manually run the stored procedure to populate the table with the data I need for the query to return the data I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option you could use:

```
EXEC('EXEC team 9596, 2; select * from tempteam')
```

or to parameterize:

```
EXEC('EXEC team ' + @p1 + ',' + @p2 + '; select * from tempteam')
```

Full repro:

```
create table test(f1 varchar(256) null)
go
create proc sp_test(@p varchar(256) = 'Hello ')
as
    insert test
    select @p
    return 1
go

declare @p varchar(256) = 'World'

EXEC('EXEC sp_test @p = ''Hello ''; select * from test')
EXEC('EXEC sp_test @p = ' + @p + '; select * from test')

drop proc sp_test
go
drop table test
go
```